# Eclipse refuses to build the war file

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I am using Java-EE Eclipse LUNA IDE and i'm trying to learn servlets.
I created a Dynamic web project and built a simple web app. The client chooses a color and the servlet writes the color's name.
After working on it far to long, Eclipse refuses to build the war file. If i understand correctly, there's should be a classes folder in the WEB-INF folder that contains the package of the servlet. unfortunately Eclipse doesn't builds this folder. 
Thanks in advance for any help.

**html code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="windows-1255">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1 style="text-align: center;">Beer Selection Page</h1>
<br><br>

<form method = "POST" action="SelectBeer.do">
 Select beer characteristics<p>
 Color:
<select name ="color" size="1">
 <option value="light">light</option>
 <option value="amber">amber</option>
 <option value="brown">brown</option>
 <option value="dark">dark</option>
</select>
<br><br>

<div style="text-align:center">
<input type = "SUBMIT">
</div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**Web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<servlet>     
 <servlet-name>Ch3 Beer</servlet-name> 
 <servlet-class>com.example.web.BeerSelect</servlet-class> 
</servlet>   

<servlet-mapping>    
 <servlet-name>Ch3 Beer</servlet-name>      
 <url-pattern>/SelectBeer.do</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping> 
</web-app>
```

Comment: There is more than one way to deploy your changes.  The WEB-INF/classes folder you mention is often referred to the "loose class" approach.  For a production application, this is typically deployed as war file.  When the war file is exploded (i.e. uncompressed), this allows you to copy individual class files the the WEB-INF/classes folder.  This is a convenience for development...

Comment: This method of deployment must be configured by the developer.  It is unlikely this is the default Eclipse configuration, as there are some implied manual steps necessary for this to work.

Comment: So, if you could share your Eclipse project setting, that would be the most relevant info and most likely to get you an answer.  And while you are it, you can remove the servlet code from your question as it is not relevant.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputations to upload a photo so i'll just write the project setting.
Inside the project (Dynamic Web Project) there are the following items: * deployment descriptor, * JAX-WS web services, * java resources(/src/com.example.web/BeerSelect.java, libraries), * Javascript Resources, *Webcontent: Meta-INF/MANIFEST.MF and WEB-INF/lib/web.xml and form.html

Comment: Or more comfortable, you can find the setting in this link:
https://drive.google.com/?tab=mo&authuser=0#folders/0B5Y-gyPmkvFjdEMydm5zcFdsY1E